# How to create my own opengl binding or library

Tags: opengl

I am relatively new to graphic programming so I wanted to start from the very basic. I see there is library like PyOpenGl which provides binding to the opengl api itself. Now, I really want to create things like PyOpenGl on my own so I can understand how everything work in the process.

Is it possible for me to creates library like PyOpenGl or GLFW? If so please give me some general tips of what should I do.

If not please explain to me why I can't create my own binding and I do apologize if my question above sounds absurd.

Comment: If you're new to graphics programming, then trying to write your own binding probably isn't that good an idea.

Comment: Yah I figure so but I just really really want to do it. Can you just give me some pointer if you know how? I am sure I will pick up the necessary skills as I move along

Comment: I don't have a link for you, sorry, but I do have to add... The low-level stuff is written in a very specific way, to support a rather tightly defined higher-level usage. If you don't understand how OpenGL operates, you will find it extremely difficult to interact with the hardware in a useful fashion.

Comment: Well I actually am a student at a UC and I have a year worth of machine code under my belt. So I would really like to dive down to the nitty gritty stuff. Even if it involves machine code.

Comment: I don't know how this works in python (you might want to add this tag if you want it in that language). On windows, you would use a combination of `LoadLibraryA`, `GetProcAddress`, `wglGetProcAddress` as explained [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions)

Comment: google for OpenGL and registering extensions. btw I suggest to download GLEW source code (static link mode) and see for your self how the things are done... The pocess is as this: 1. create OpenGL context 2. scan extention string 3. bind available extensions to function pointers. The headers are in glext.h.  booth extensions description and actual glext.h can be downloaded from nVidia developer sites

Comment: Your best bet would be to parse all extension txt description files  and automatically create the binding code ... do it manually is insanity these days ... as the extensions are changing so you would recode the stuff manually otherwise really often .... see [NVIDIA OpenGL Specs](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-opengl-specs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PyOpenGL` is a fairly thin wrapper that, for the most part, simply turns Python function calls into calls of native machine code functions of the same name. There are a few little details like calling conventions in the mix, but these are actually boring stuff. The fact is that (as far as OpenGL is concerned) the source code you write in Python with PyOpenGL looks almost identical to the source code you'd write in C. There are a few "smart" things PyOpenGL does, like providing means to interface NumPy arrays to OpenGL calls that take a data pointer parameter, but that's just house keeping.

And when you do OpenGL calls in C or – even more extreme – assembly language (perfectly possible) that's the lowest level you can go (with OpenGL), short of writing your own GPU device driver. And writing a GPU device driver is super hard work; it takes literally millions of lines of C code (NVidia's OpenGL implementation is said to consist of about ~40M LoC, there are open source drivers for AMD and Intel GPUs, and each of them have MLoC, too).

If you're interested in some middle ground, have a look at the Vulkan API. If writing higher level wrappers for graphics is your thing I'd suggest you implement some higher level API / renderer for Vulkan and interface it to Python. This is likely to be much more rewarding, as a learning experience (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

The OpenGL API lives in the driver for the graphics card. All OpenGL functions are there. You only need to know how to get them. As Spektre said, the proccess is:

1. Create an OpenGL context. This is a job for the OS. Each OS has its
   way and its issues. Read https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions
2. Define function pointers as `glext.h` does and then extract them from
   the driver. Apart from standard OpenGL funcs, vendors add their own
   ones, called "extensions". You can see how GLEW does this job. If you want to set **all** functions and extensions then make a script that uses `glext.h` because there are about one thousand of them.

You can download `glext.h` from https://www.opengl.org/registry/

Doing something like GLFW requires, added to the previous two points, knowing how to create a window and handle its messages for keyboard and mouse. Again this is OS dependant. On Windows there is a way. On Linux it depends on the window manager used, GTK+ for example. Or X11 directly. Or...

Anyhow my best advise is that you can read how GLEW and GLFW did, looking into their code. BUT **don't lose much time on it**. Prefer getting experience on OpenGL and let those "diggins" for later time.